# How to generate multilevel nested numbered list in Java using Apache POI XWPFDocument?

Tags: java, apache-poi, xwpf

I want to create a list like this using apache POI word :

```
1.A  
1.1  A 11  
1.2  A 12  

2.B  
2.1  B 21  
2.2  B 23
```

...... and so on ....

My Data is dynamic.

I am able to create a normal list. Also I have gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310020/how-to-create-multilevel-bullets-and-numbering-from-java-using-apache-poi-xwpfdo) and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510069/apache-poi-bullets-and-numbering). But couldn't find anything to do it. Also searched in google but did not find any documentation about it. Would anyone please help me out to find docs or solution to it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not currently supported in POI. It is quite complex. You will have to use the CT classes to do it. To get started you will want to download the standard from here. http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm

Parts 1, 3, and 4 are the most useful.

POI uses the 1st edition standards. That is equivalent to Word 2007.

Comment: Thanks !! May be should not be depend on POI for solving this.

Comment: If you end up working out a solution using POI, perhaps you could donate it back to the community?

Comment: I think so. But don't quote me on that.