# Apache POI numbered list

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi

I am using `apache-poi` to write some data in a MS Word document. I've already spent several hours trying to figure out **how to create a numbered list** but I haven't achieved any results.

I've gone through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31310020/how-to-create-multilevel-bullets-and-numbering-from-java-using-apache-poi-xwpfdo), [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39510069/apache-poi-bullets-and-numbering) and multiple other questions. Taking into account that `apache-poi` has the worst kind of documentation I've ever seen (basically there's no documentation at all) and their classes and methods have absolutely mad names it's too difficult for me to understand such complex examples.

**Q:** *Could anyone provide a concise code snippet to create such a list in MS Word document:*

1. One
2. Two
3. Three

Thank's in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First I thought there is an issue with my code linked in your question, since `apache poi` is highly in development and sometimes code which has worked in earlier versions does not work any more in current versions. But simple copy&paste code leads to working code even in current version 3.16.

So I have removed all the table stuff, since the linked question was about a list in table cells and I got:

```
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTLvl;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.STNumberFormat;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import java.math.BigInteger;

public class CreateWordSimplestNumberingList {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run=paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The list:");

  ArrayList<String> documentList = new ArrayList<String>(
   Arrays.asList(
    new String[] {
     "One",
     "Two",
     "Three"
    }));

  CTAbstractNum cTAbstractNum = CTAbstractNum.Factory.newInstance();
  //Next we set the AbstractNumId. This requires care. 
  //Since we are in a new document we can start numbering from 0. 
  //But if we have an existing document, we must determine the next free number first.
  cTAbstractNum.setAbstractNumId(BigInteger.valueOf(0));

/* Bullet list
  CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
  cTLvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0)); // set indent level 0
  cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.BULLET);
  cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("•");
*/

///* Decimal list
  CTLvl cTLvl = cTAbstractNum.addNewLvl();
  cTLvl.setIlvl(BigInteger.valueOf(0)); // set indent level 0
  cTLvl.addNewNumFmt().setVal(STNumberFormat.DECIMAL);
  cTLvl.addNewLvlText().setVal("%1.");
  cTLvl.addNewStart().setVal(BigInteger.valueOf(1));
//*/

  XWPFAbstractNum abstractNum = new XWPFAbstractNum(cTAbstractNum);

  XWPFNumbering numbering = document.createNumbering();

  BigInteger abstractNumID = numbering.addAbstractNum(abstractNum);

  BigInteger numID = numbering.addNum(abstractNumID);

  for (String string : documentList) {
   paragraph = document.createParagraph();
   paragraph.setNumID(numID);
   run=paragraph.createRun(); 
   run.setText(string); 
  }

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordSimplestNumberingList.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

This results in:

[image]

What you need to know is, that a `*.docx` file is simply a `ZIP` file containing a directory structure with `XML`files in it. So what I do if I have the requirement to create a special `Word` document, is to create the simplest form of that document using `Word` itself. Then I unzip the `*.docx` file and find the main story in `/word/document.xml`. With numberings (lists) I find there:

```
<w:numId w:val="1"/>
```

within the paragraphs. This are references to `mumId`s in `/word/numbering.xml`. Well have a look at this, I find something like:

```
<w:numbering>
 <w:abstractNum w:abstractNumId="0">
  <w:lvl>
   <w:start w:val="1"/>
   <w:numFmt w:val="decimal"/>
   <w:lvlText w:val="%1."/>
  </w:lvl>
 </w:abstractNum>
 <w:num w:numId="1">
  <w:abstractNumId w:val="0"/>
 </w:num>
</w:numbering>
```

A `abstractNum` having the definition for levels (`lvl`) of the numbering and a `num` having the `numId` and a reference to the `abstractNum`.

Then you need to know that `apache poi` `XWPF` bases on `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.*`. So we have [XWPFNumbering](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/class-use/XWPFNumbering.html) and [XWPFAbstractNum](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFAbstractNum.html) but `XWPFAbstractNum` can only be created using `org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.CTAbstractNum` So how to find documentation about `CTAbstractNum`. Well Google it and find http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/wordprocessingml/x2006/main/CTAbstractNum.java

Comment: Many thanks to you for your time! You really helped.